# Allow all MySQL DB fields to be nullable - Laravel 5.3

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, database-migration

I have MySQL DB created with Laravel migrations and I want to allow all fields in all tables to be nullable (except PKs & FKs of course). 
There is no problem to drop db and rerun migrations, but should I modify the existing migrations and add ->nullable() to each property ? or should I create new migrations to do this changes ? or is there another better way ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a MySQL function that loops through all table fields and make it nullable, your (the best in this cause, in my opinion), add `->nullable()` in all migrations.

Comment: You mean just change in the existing migrations ?
ex : change $table->string('name');  
to $table->string('name')->nullable(); ? and then drop db and rerun migrations ? @Gabriel Caruso

Comment: Yeah @RowaydaKhayri. I've done this many and many times, 100% work. Just be careful with foreing keys, check them all to not be nullable, but, as you ask, your PK and FK won't be!

Answer (score 2):

The standard practice is to make new migrations for each change to your schema, otherwise you can impact the ability of your application to rollback and migrate forward again.